# There has been a critical error on this website

Tags: plugins, errors

When updating Elementor on my site joyorama.com, my website stopped working. I received an email saying there is an error with Elementor and with a recovery mode link. When entering recovery mode, after reinstalling stuff a few times I got it working but it stopped again. The link is expired by now.

I can go to my main home page now but it is empty. When I try to go to `/wp-admin` I get the error `There has been a critical error on this website` and it wont let me access the control panel or whatever its called. When turning on debugging by editing the correct file, I get this on my home page-

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid function name in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WP_Block_Supports' not found in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_robots' not found or invalid function name in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_replace_insecure_home_url' not found or invalid function name in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292

And I get this on my admin page-

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare retrieve_password() (previously declared in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-login.php:357) in /home/vol14_2/epizy.com/epiz_26801828/joyorama.com/htdocs/wp-includes/user.php on line 2671

What do I do? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall wordpress and start over with the backup I have? Or is there some way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: rename the plugins folder to check if plugin is causing this error

Comment: I already tried it, no difference.

Comment: This looks like a failed/incomplete automatic update. I suggest updating WordPress manually: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: Ok I will try that when I have time

Comment: Hey it worked! Thanks a lot!